# How many cache-hits and cache-miss does this code generate?

Tags: caching, memory-management, computer-science, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers

I have a code and I need to analyze how many cache-miss and cache-hits occur when it is executed.
The cache memory has 1024 lines organized in blocks with **4 words of 1 byte each**. The replacement method is **direct mapping**.

The code:

```
    int N = 1024;
    byte x[N], y[N];

    for(int i = 0; i<N-1;i++){
        for(int j=0; j<N;j++){
            x[i] = x[i+1]*y[j];
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I supposed you're also supposed to assume no hardware prefetching?  Are you supposed to assume that x[] and y[] are contiguous with each other?  Or perhaps that factors out regardless of the relative offset, creating a conflict miss.

Comment: Are you also supposed to assume a braindead compiler that redundantly writes `x[i]` repeatedly for every `j` even though `i` is unchanging?  That's a weird access pattern that in real life would optimize `x[i]` and `x[i+1]` into registers, or even better just only do the last iteration of the inner loop and only ever read `y[j]`.  i.e. is that supposed to be pseudo-code for asm (so in C terms, the arrays should be treated as `volatile`), or is it supposed to be actual C compiled by a normal optimizing compiler?